# How to map keyboard to mouse buttons in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, remapping, keymap

Severe RSI is causing me pain each time I click the mouse.

I would like to map the right CMD and OPT (which I never use) to function as left and right mouse button.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

[Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)(formerly known as KeyRemap4MacBook) does exactly that. It allows you to remap the right Command button to a left click:

[image]

The same is possible for the right option key too. It worked for me on a 2011 MacBook Pro running Snow Leopard—couldn't test it on a "normal" Mac, but it should work regardless of that.

---

There's an app called [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722). In its *Preferences*, under *Keyboard*, you can set any keyboard shortcut to map to a primary or secondary click. The problem is that `cmd` and `alt` are modifier keys, so they aren't a keyboard shortcut recognized by the app.

Another program called [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) might be worth mentioning as well, but it does not emulate clicks.

Comment: None of those will make the key bound to a secondary click act like the Windows menu key though. You'll still need to move the cursor before pressing the key.

Comment: @Lri I didn't experience any problems with it – what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Like you can't use the primary or secondary click keys to perform actions on items focused with the keyboard.

Comment: I have never used this functionality in OSX.   If I can move the mouse with one hand and click with the other, this is enough.

Comment: @Pi That should work then, yes. It did for me!

Comment: Can a key be mapped to "Hold mouse button"?